# Post to two Tables Loopback

Tags: json, api, post, has-many, loopback

I have a problem with loopback, I want to try to POST to another table. but it can't. here the code that I want to POST to Loopback Explorer
at http://localhost:1337/explorer/#!/Order/Order_create

```
    {
  "Code": "ASDASDASDE",
  "DP": 0,
  "Discount": 0,
  "DiscountNominal": 0,
  "TotalPrice": 0,
  "RequestDate": "string",
  "DeliveryDate": "2017-06-22T07:14:18.815Z",
  "TotalQty": 0,
  "Destination": "string",
  "Phone": "string",
  "Status": "string",
  "PaymentType": "string",
  "DealerCode": "D912839",
  "Active": true,
  "Deleted": true,
  "CreatedBy": "string",
  "CreatedDate": "2017-06-22T07:14:18.815Z",
  "CreateAgent": "string",
  "UpdatedBy": "string",
  "UpdatedDate": "2017-06-22T07:14:18.815Z",
  "UpdateAgent": "string",
  "KioskCode": "A1234",
"orderDetails":[{
  "Code": "ASD123",
  "IsRetur": true,
  "Price": 0,
  "IMEI": "string",
  "Status": "string",
  "OrderCode": "ASDASDASDE",
  "ProductCode": "SM-1923",
  "Active": true,
  "Deleted": true,
  "CreatedBy": "string",
  "CreatedDate": "2017-06-22T07:14:19.045Z",
  "CreateAgent": "string",
  "UpdatedBy": "string",
  "UpdatedDate": "2017-06-22T07:14:19.045Z",
  "UpdateAgent": "string"
}]
}
```

Let's say, I want to POST to table Order, and table Order detail in the single quote of JSON. the Order Table has been inserted, but the order detail table couldn't.

here my Order.JSON

```
{
  "name": "Order",
  "plural": "Order",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": {}
  },
  "properties": {
    "Code": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    ....
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "Dealer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Dealer",
      "foreignKey": "DealerCode"
    },
    "orderDetails": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "OrderDetail",
      "foreignKey": "OrderCode"
    },
    "Kiosk": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Kiosk",
      "foreignKey": "KioskCode"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

here my orderDetail.JSON

```
{
  "name": "OrderDetail",
  "plural": "orderDetails",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "TimeStamp": {}
  },
  "properties": {
    "Code": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    }
.....
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "Order": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Order",
      "foreignKey": "OrderCode"
    },
    "Product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "ProductCode"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

The order has primaryKey: Code and orderDetails has a foreign key: OrderCode that References to Order: Code.  what the solution ?? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may follow these steps:
1. define a remote method in your order.js file:

```
Order.remoteMethod('saveNewOrder', {
    accepts: {arg: 'orderInstance', type: 'json'},
    http: {path:'/order-create', verb:'post'},
    returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'json'}
});
```

2. define the saveNewOrder function with the "orderInstance" argument:

```
Order.saveNewOrder = function(orderInstance, cb){
    var order = new Order(orderInstance["order"])
    order.save().then(function(savedOrder,err){
    if(err)
        throw err
    else
        savedOrder.orderDetails.create(orderInstance["orderDetails"], function(err, createdOrderDetails){
            if(err)
                throw err
            else
                console.log("insertion done:",createdOrderDetails)
        })
    })
}
```

3. change your json to match this format:

   ```
   {
   "orderInstance":{
       "order":{
           "Code": "ASDASDASDE",
           "DP": 0,
           "Discount": 0,
           ...
       },
       "orderDetails":[{
           "Code": "ASD123",
           "IsRetur": true,
           "Price": 0,
           ...
       }]
       }
   }
   ```
4. post your json to http://localhost:3000/api/orders/order-create

Comment: hi , Tash , thanks for the answer , it looks like perfect , but when i try that remote code , i founded the error , because the app.models. was no more needed . Great! cheers!